# How can I call Maven programmatically from within a plugin without using a process invocation?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

I'd like to call Maven goals from within a plugin and am reluctant to accept the cost of forking a process as the initialisation. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: The question is why do you need that? Why not using the lifecycle of Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise Take the Maven Release Plugin for example - that forks Maven because it needs control over the lifecycle, and needs to operate on arbitrary projects checked out from SCM. My plugin performs releases too. Unfortunately I couldn't use the Maven Release Plugin because its interaction with our "AccuRev" SCM software was flaky, and it had one or two bugs elsewhere too.

Comment: Maven Release Plugin uses Maven-Invoker-Plugin to run maven in background. Furthermore why not fixing the bugs of the SCM providers for AccuRev instead starting from scratch ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Ideally I would fix the OSS projects, but I'm not an experienced OSS committer and do not have commit access to the projects (and am on a deadline). Not only that, but our release process is sufficiently specialised to make it easier to roll our own.

Comment: But you can put some kind of issues into the tracking system (JIRA). You will never get an OSS committer until you start with sending patches...But it will be sufficient to file in issues in the systems. Furthermore we are always on deadlines in every project ;-)

Comment: @khmarbaise that's what I mean - I haven't had the prior experience to show for myself, so I have no expectations of gaining commit rights anytime soon. And because I'm working to deadlines I cannot afford to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is a supported approach but it worked for me.

```
/**
 * @parameter expression="${session}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
 private MavenSession session;

/**
 * @component
 * @readonly
 */
 private Maven maven;
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${project.remoteArtifactRepositories}"
 * @readonly
 **/
protected List<ArtifactRepository> remoteArtifactRepositories;
/**
 * The project's remote repositories to use for the resolution of plugins
 * and their dependencies.
 * 
 * @parameter default-value="${project.pluginArtifactRepositories}"
 * @readonly
 */
private List<ArtifactRepository> pluginArtifactRepositories;
/**
 * @parameter default-value="${localRepository}"
 * @readonly
 * */
private ArtifactRepository localRepository;
```

...

```
List<String> goals = ...
File pomFile = ...
MavenExecutionRequest req = new DefaultMavenExecutionRequest();
req.setPom(pomFile);
req.setBaseDirectory(pomFile.getParentFile());
req.setGoals(goals);
req.setProxies(session.getSettings().getProxies());
req.setMirrors(session.getSettings().getMirrors());
req.setLocalRepository(localRepository);
req.setRemoteRepositories(remoteArtifactRepositories);
req.setPluginArtifactRepositories(pluginArtifactRepositories);
MavenExecutionResult result = session.execute(req);
```

To introspect the processing, you can subclass AbstractExecutionListener and use req.setExecutionListener() to apply it.

Comment: I tried this but could'nt find a way to intialise most of these are interfaces.
Like for creating maven session one needs a plexus container which is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

What i missed to mentioned was this:

http://timmoore.github.com/mojo-executor/

Comment: I did have a play with this but it seemed to take a while to initialise each plugin run, hence appeared to be forking. Running with the code in my answer seems to be faster.